# Ext4magic not listing files properly in the Home dir

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, undelete

I'm trying to recover files and directories accidentally deleted from my home folder. I have ext4magic working, as I can create and then delete a test file in a subdirectory 'undeltest' and then recover it. However, when use try the same procedure for the home directory, I get a long list of other files. The strange part is that even though I'm using very small time step backward, as in only several minutes, the long list of files seems to be several weeks ago. It has a bunch of avi files in Trash dir that ironically caused my initial data loss, because I was trying to delete them to free up space and never wanted to use a Trash folder anyway.

I'm trying to solve this small mystery because the same thing happens when I try to recover the non-test files from the home dir. I get this same list, that doesn't include the files I'm missing, but I know the timestamp was from before the deletion, and I'm listing all files deleted 'after' that point.

Is the file Journal interfering somehow? Why does the test case work in a subdirectory, but not in my home dir? Very unexpected behavior. I cant see the logic in it. If there is a better tool, please suggest. The grammatical flaws in the manual doesn't give me a great deal of confidence, but as far as I know this is the only working program that recovers the directory structure.

```
xxx@pc:~/undeltest$ sudo ext4magic /dev/sda11 -a 1600125847 -f /home/xxx/undeltest/ -l 
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Filesystem in use: /dev/sda11

Using  internal Journal at Inode 8
Activ Time after  : Mon Sep 14 16:24:07 2020
Activ Time before : Mon Sep 14 16:47:29 2020
Inode found "/home/xxx/undeltest"   567136 
Inode 567136 is allocated
  100%   /home/xxx/undeltest/test4 
ext4magic : EXIT_SUCCESS


xxx@pc:~/undeltest$ sudo ext4magic /dev/sda11 -a 1600125847 -f /home/xxx/ -l           
Filesystem in use: /dev/sda11

Using  internal Journal at Inode 8
Activ Time after  : Mon Sep 14 16:24:07 2020
Activ Time before : Mon Sep 14 16:47:35 2020
Inode found "/home/xxx"   560924 
Inode 560924 is allocated
  100%   /home/xxx/.face.icon 
  100%   /home/xxx/.PlayOnLinux  
...
  100%   /home/xxx/.local/share/Trash/files/2019-09-30 12 22 22-A.avi 
... 
[long list of 100s of files]
```