# ext4magic does not recognize directory

Tags: directory, data-recovery, systemd-journald

## Situation

I deleted a great number of files with Ranger and now I am trying to use ext4magic to recover them. I am on Ubuntu 20.04, and I am not a power user. :)

I have a single drive with two partitions where I store everything on `sda2` only.

```
user@machine$ mount | grep /dev/sd
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Now, the files I deleted were under `/home/username/Downloads/compressed`.

## Preparation

In order to ext4magic even consider this drive I had to do the following (based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193510/316807)):

1. Launch recovery at boot and choose 'root mode'
2. Mount an external drive and navigate to there
3. Change the `sda2` status to read-only with `mount -o remount,ro /dev/sda2`
4. run ext4magic

## Problem

ext4magic does not seem to recognize the directory where I deleted the files.

```
root@barat:/mnt# ext4magic /dev/sda2 -a $(date -d "-1 days" +%s) -f home/username/Downloads/compressed -l

Filesystem in use: /dev/sda2

Using  internal Journal at Inode 8
Activ Time after  : Wed Mar  3 19:36:06 2021
Activ Time before : Thu Mar  4 19:36:06 2021
Warning: error-NR 2133571476 can not found file: home/username/Downloads
Error: Inode not found for "home/username/Downloads/compressed"
Check the valid PATHNAME "home/username/Downloads/compressed" and the BEFORE option "Thu Mar  4 19:36:06 2021"
ext4magic : EXIT_SUCCESS
```

To be more precise, it does not recognize its 'parent' directory (i.e. "Downloads").

Strangely, however, it does show me a list of files when I try it on the home directory (that is, one of its parent):

```
ext4magic /dev/sda2 -a $(date -d "-1 days" +%s) -f home/username -l
```

This list contains files from other subdirectories of the home folder (e.g. `.local`) and it seems to show files deleted much earlier. However, I do not see any mention of files from the "Downloads" directory.

(There is a similar issue [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275182/ext4magic-not-listing-files-properly-in-the-home-dir), but without any error message and without an answer).

## Question

What is happening here and what can I do to recover the deleted files?

## Update

I also tried to use `debugfs` (and there 'lsdel') to find deleted inodes (based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80285/316807)) but it came up empty.